# NativeExpressAdView cannot be resolved to a type?

Tags: admob, native

I am trying to put native Admob inside list item using Eclipse, but it keeps showing this error:

> NativeExpressAdView cannot be resolved to a type

I'm pretty sure had the latest version of google play service. Other format ads are working fine (banner, interstitial, reward).